# Recommendations for artificial neural network simulation basic software

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I have a single threshold unit truth table to simulate for 100 epochs, with my input of the learning curve, target, activation, bias and weight to detect errors. Is there some software which can do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have [neural network toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/neuralnet/) on Matlab you can use it.
You can design your network on it and feed learning curve via input and set target and bias or other parameters then run learning for 100 epochs.

SciLab is an open-source software and is the best free option instead of Matlab. You can use [Neural Network Toolbox](http://www.scilab.org/contrib/index_contrib.php?page=displayContribution&fileID=1112) of it for your purpose.